# BizTalk Server 2010 Cumulative Update 6 - Compatibility with BTAHL7?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, btahl7

We recently installed BizTalk Server 2010 CU 6 in a development environment for testing.

After the installation, the error below was generated when an HL7 message was submitted through an MLLP adapter to a request response receive location with the BTAHL7ReceivePipeline receive pipeline and BTAHL7SendPipeline send pipeline.

These pipelines are supplied in the BTAHL7 and have not been customized. We applied the update in an environment with our current state BizTalk Server 2010 CU5 and BizTalk Adapter Pack 2010 CU2 and in one with BizTalk Server 2010 CU5, BizTalk Adapter Pack 2010 CU3 and BTAHL7 Accelerator hot fixes 2564013, 2607536,2702143,2713884,2732905,2758524.

In both cases, the same error was encountered, the windows updates are up to date as of October 25th 2014. Has anyone else experienced this issue?

```
A pipeline component in the receive pipeline:"<pipeline info - version, culture and 
public key token>" is using the message context properties "BTS.MessageDestination" or 
"BTS.SuspendMessageOnRoutingFailure" in a unsupported fashion. The pipeline processing is 
being terminated."
```

----Edit----

This ended up being a bug in Microsoft's Biztalk CU 6. We were able to replicate it with all the basic information and a new CU was created to address this issue.

Comment: It should work with CU6, have you tried some tests on XmlReceive pipeline without HL7 accelerator. May be there is a problem overall. Otherwise try repairing HL7 accelerator

Comment: I've not tried repairing the HL7 accelerator, but one of the first installs was done without the HL7 accelerator updates.